# "On Demand" dependency injection for dynamically instantiated classes

Tags: c#, events, reflection, dependency-injection, delegates

In my application, I have a class called `EventTriggerActionService`, which is responsible for instantiating custom actions that reside in different assemblies. It uses the class name and assembly name to load the module via Reflection, and executes it.

My main problem is: How do I inject the required dependencies into these custom actions? My actions all derive from a base class called `ActionBase`.

My initial solution was to first supply all the dependencies via constructor injection by just adding them as parameters in the `(ActionBase)Activator.CreateInstance();`, but this was problematic, because I didn't want to force all of my derived actions to take in the dependencies of other actions.

Here is my second solution: I decided to use events to put "Dependency Providers" in `EventTriggerActionService`. Using this approach, all of the dependencies for all custom actions will be injected in `EventTriggerActionService`, and the custom action will request the dependency by firing the event.

Here is my `EventTriggerActionService`:

```
public class EventTriggerActionService
{
    private IEmailerFactory _emailerFactory;
    public EventTriggerActionService(IEmailerFactory emailerFactory) 
    {
        _emailerFactory = emailerFactory;
    }

    public void Execute(EventTriggerAction eventTriggerAction, EventContext context)
    {   
        var assemblyName = eventTriggerAction.EventAction.EventActionHandlerAssembly;
        var className = eventTriggerAction.EventAction.EventActionHandlerClass;

        Assembly actionHandlerAssembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
        Type actionHandlerType = actionHandlerAssembly.GetType(className);

        var action = (ActionBase)Activator.CreateInstance(); // Instantiate the action by its base class, ActionBase

        action.Arguments = data.Arguments; // This is a dictionary that contains the arguments of the action

        // Register all the dependency providers here
        GetEmailer emailerHandler = GetEmailer;
        actionHandlerType.GetEvent("GetEmailer").AddEventHandler(action, emailerHandler); // Register the event handler

        action.Execute(); // Execute the Action
    }

    // The custom action "Requests" a dependency by firing this event
    private void GetEmailer(ref IEmailer emailer)
    {
        emailer = _emailerFactory.Create();
    }
}

public delegate void GetEmailer(ref IEmailer emailer);
```

This is `ActionBase`:

```
public abstract class ActionBase
{
    public event GetEmailer GetEmailer;

    private IEmailer _emailer;

    protected IEmailer Emailer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_emailer == null)
            {
                GetEmailer(ref _emailer);
            }
            return _emailer;
        }
    }

    protected Dictionary<string,string> Arguments { get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // Perform some common logic here
        ExecuteAction(); // Execute the custom action
    }

    public abstract ResultBase ExecuteAction();
}
```

This is one of my custom actions:

```
public class SimpleEmailSender : ActionBase
{
    public override ResultBase ExecuteAction()
    {
        Emailer.Send(Arguments["EmailBody"]);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `EventTriggerActionService` resides in an isolated library, and will be used by different consumer applications. The consumer applications can choose to use IoC containers or just do Poor Man's DI.

My question is, is there a more optimal solution to my problem? I think my solution definitely addresses the issue of forcing the dependencies to all derived actions.

Comment: @DavidG Keep in mind that the code snippet that I provided is just a prototype. I'll have 20+ custom actions, and each action will have 6+ dependencies. This means I need to put ~120 delegates in my `EventTriggerActionService` and the same number of corresponding events in `ActionBase`. That is why I decided to post here.

Comment: TBH that sounds like it's an even better fit for CR than SO.

Comment: @DavidG, I flagged it for migration to CR as you requested.

Comment: I hope you read their rules first, I don't use that site so I cannot be sure it is on topic there. Perhaps someone from codereview.stackexchange.com could confirm though, I think they get flagged by comments like this?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, we do monitor comment mentionning CR, but no, hypothetical code is off-topic there (as could be indicated by comments such as `// Perform some common logic here`).

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Thanks for reply, I'm always nervous suggesting CR as I have never looked at your rules there.

Comment: @DavidG Then if you have to only remember one thing, I’ll quote an exerpt from our on-topic page: "If you have a working piece of code from your project and are looking for open-ended feedback […] then you are in the right place!"

Comment: @MathiasEttinger But this is a working piece of code, which is why I thought it would work on CR...

Comment: Can you elaborate why your constructor injection didn't work? Did you force the order of the services or did you resolve then at runtime? Wouldn't a simple DI container that can resolve services be enough here?

Comment: @RMH, After using constructor injection, I realized that every single derived class should get the injected services and pass them to the base class. This was undesirable, because not every derived class needs those services. Worse thing is that if we add more injected services, we would have to go and update all derived actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your main problem resides with your base class `ActionBase`.

The `Action` method within this class is basically a wrapper that executes some common logic before invoking the actual action.
The common knowledge requires some external services (here the `IEmailer`) to function, which dependency you do not want to force upon the derived classes.

---

Maybe a simpler approach to using events would be to make a public `IEmailer` property and set it when the action is created in the `EventTriggerActionService.Execute` method.

This would prevent you from having to pass down the reference through the constructor, while still being able to access the `IEmailer instance`.
You would get something along the lines of:

```
public abstract class ActionBase
{
    protected IEmailer Emailer { get; set; }

    protected Dictionary<string,string> Arguments { get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // Do something with Emailer.
        ExecuteAction(); // Execute the custom action
    }

    public abstract ResultBase ExecuteAction();
}

public class EventTriggerActionService
{
    // omit for readability 
    public void Execute(EventTriggerAction eventTriggerAction, EventContext context)
    {   
        // omit for readability

        var action = (ActionBase)Activator.CreateInstance(); // Instantiate the action by its base class, ActionBase

        action.Arguments = data.Arguments; // This is a dictionary that contains the arguments of the action
        action.Emailer = _emailerFactory.Create();

        // omit for readability
    }
    // omit for readability
}
```

---

However, as you have control over the way the actions get invoked, why force the common logic into the base class?

You can easily extract the common logic and separate it from the action.
For example:

```
public interface IActionBase
{
    ResultBase ExecuteAction();
}

public class SimpleEmailSender : IActionBase
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> arguments;
    private IEmailer Emailer;

    public SimpleEmailSender(Dictionary<string, string> arguments, IEmailer emailer)
    {
        this.arguments = arguments;
        this.emailer = emailer;
    }

    public override ResultBase ExecuteAction()
    {
        this.emailer.Send(Arguments["EmailBody"]);
        return null;
    }
}   

public class EventTriggerActionService
{
    // omit for readability 
    public void Execute(EventTriggerAction eventTriggerAction, EventContext context)
    {   
        // omit for readability

        this.RunPreLogic();
        action.ExecuteAction();
        this.RunPostLogic();

        // omit for readability
    }

    public void RunPreLogic() {}        
    public void RunPostLogic() {}

    // omit for readability
}
```

As you can see from the example, the logic is removed from the base class. Releasing any derived class from the need to supply those services.
The only thing left is to inject the required services into the constructor of the created class.

The DI containers I've used in the past always provided some way of injecting services. If you cannot (or don't want to) use a container, it shouldn't be too hard to extract constructor information and resolve it yourself.

*If you are using the ASP.NET Core, the default Microsoft dependency injection provides the utility class `ActivatorUtilities` for this ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities?view=aspnetcore-2.0))*

---

In the case you do not want your common logic in the `EventTriggerActionService`, you can always extract it into a separate service, or make a special action that handles the common logic.

Comment: Ended up refactoring my code after reading your first approach. Things are much simpler now. The only major difference in my implementation, however, is that I only set the factory properties in ActionBase. That way, the "On-Demand" nature of this implementation will be preseved. For example, I'm setting IEmailerFactory, ITemplateFactory, etc, and the derived actions will just use these factories to instantiate their needed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Because `EventTriggerActionService` don't know what type it's dealing with, it has to let custom actions decide what they want. So, I think that service locator pattern is a good solution for this. Assume you have service locator defined on `EventTriggerActionService` side like:

```
public static class ServiceLocator
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> container = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public static void RegisterService(string name, Type implType)
    {
        container.Add(name, implType);
    }

    public static objcet GetService(string name)
    {
        return Actinator.CreateInstance(container[name]);
    }
}
```

Change your `ActionBase` and custom actions a little like:

```
public abstract class ActionBase
{
    private static MethodInfo getServiceMI;

    static ActionBase()
    {
        // Find out which assembly implement ServiceLocator.
        var asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().First(x => x.GetTypes().Any(y => y.Name == "ServiceLocator"));
        // Get MethodInfo of ServiceLocator.GetService.
        getServiceMI = asm.GetType("ServiceLocator").GetMethod("GetService", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    }

    protected static object GetService(string name)
    {
        return getServiceMI.Invoke(null, new object[] { name });
    }

    // And your original staff.
}

public class ActionSample : ActionBase
{
    IDependency1 d1 = GetService("name1");
    ...
    IDependencyN dN = GetService("nameN");

    public override ResultBase ExecuteAction()
    {
        d1.DoSomething();
        ...
        dN.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Finally, in `EventTriggerActionService`, register all dependencies before create and instance of custom action.

```
public class EventTriggerActionService
{
    static EventTriggerActionService()
    {
        ServiceLocator.RegisterService("name1", typeof(dependencyImpl1));
        ...
        ServiceLocator.RegisterService("nameN", typeof(dependencyImplN));
    }

    public void Execute(EventTriggerAction eventTriggerAction, EventContext context)
    {   
        var assemblyName = eventTriggerAction.EventAction.EventActionHandlerAssembly;
        var className = eventTriggerAction.EventAction.EventActionHandlerClass;

        Assembly actionHandlerAssembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);  
        var action = (ActionBase)Activator.CreateInstance(); // Instantiate the action by its base class, ActionBase
        action.Arguments = data.Arguments; // This is a dictionary that contains the arguments of the action

        action.Execute(); // Execute the Action
    }
}
```

All codes there are just for showing the idea. Your can customize `ServiceLocator` or other things to suit your purpose.

Comment: So, I've been avoiding the Service Locator Pattern since Mark Seeman has said that it is a [very bad anti pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: Yes, service locator pattern has a lot of issues, but it still have its postion in programming world. When the dependency tree is not fix, that is, creator don't know what kind of object it's creating, dependency injection will be difficult to perform. In other hand, service locator will work fine. I did't recommend you use service locator pattern in you whole project. But for the problem you post, it's a effective solution.

Comment: In the end, you can hold on to use dependency injection with a IoC container. But with IoC container, you still can't avoid any down side of service locator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but @RMH's suggestion helped me refactor my code to a cleaner implementation. Cheers.